# MetConv.txt error on Office 2007 (Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, word-2007

I've installed a MACRO in MS-word2007 (was working correctly until then) and sometimes (not always), when I use the Macro, this error popup appears

> An error has occurred in the MetConv.txt file, refer to the
>   MetConv.log file

I've searched for a solution and the recurrent one is to disable 'features'. Obviously if i disable the 'feature', te macro doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it installing the **VC++ 2008 runtime** (for the OS + ServicePack i was using).